# How to output 0x0a in C without 0x0d?

Tags: c

When I outputed **0x0a** (\n) to file using putc() and viewed it in a HEX-viewer, there was **0x0d** (\r) in the previous byte.

I used latest MinGW to compile the program.

How do I output 0x0a on its own?

Comment: There's not nearly enough here to tell us what you might be doing wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Send your actual code

Comment: Did you open your file in binary mode?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 FILE *f;
     f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
 //fprintf(f, "\n");
        putc('\n', f);

 return 0;
}`

Comment: @EsmaeelE don't post solutions in the comment section

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must be working on a DOS/Windows system. This linefeed translation is a MS legacy feature for text files. You can open the file in "binary" mode, then line ends will not be translated:

```
FILE *fp=fopen("file.name","wb");//"b" means binary
putc('\n',fp);
```

Comment: Line-end translation is required by the C standard in systems in which a newline is not a single `\n` character. That's the case under Windows (all versions) and will continue to be the case into the forseeable future. So calling it a "legacy feature" is a little misleading.